# Why doesn't msg.message ever equal WM_QUIT in my program

Tags: c++, winapi, message-queue

I have a program that uses peekmessage instead of get message and it is supposed to break if `msg.message` ever equals `WM_QUIT` but it never equals and my program never ends.

```
    MSG msg = { };
    while (TRUE)
    {
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
            break;
        }
        if (screen == TITLESCREEN) {
            drawTitleScreen();
        }

        if (screen == GAMESCREEN) {
            drawGameScreen();
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            destroyRecorces();
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_SIZE:
        {
            if (pRenderTarget != NULL)
            {
                GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);

                D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right, rc.bottom);
                pRenderTarget->Resize(size);

            }
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_GETMINMAXINFO:
        {
            LPMINMAXINFO lpMMI = (LPMINMAXINFO)lParam;
            lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.x = 300;
            lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.y = 300;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

when the window closes [postQuitMessage();](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postquitmessage) is supposed to send a `WM_QUIT` message but `msg.message` never equals `WM_QUIT`

Comment: Your PeekMessage is in a loop. It will never get to your if statements.

Comment: PeekMessage returns 0 when there are no messages in the loop

Comment: OK but there's no guarantee WM_QUIT was the last message. And it will not hurt you to put the if statements into the peek loop.

Comment: I put the msg.message == WM_QUIT into the peek loop after DispatchMessage and it still doesn't ever end the program

Comment: if i add 2 of the same if statement, one to break out of peek loop and one to break out of the while loop it works

Comment: The code passes `WM_QUIT` to `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage` (which it's not supposed to do), then keeps looping if more messages are queued. Instead, you need to check for `WM_QUIT` inside the `PeekMessage` loop, and `return` when detected, not just `break`.

Comment: so the proper way is to put the check before translate message and return 0

Comment: Check inside the loop, and set a flag if you see WM_QUIT. Then test for the flag outside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike `GetMessage()`, which returns `0` when `WM_QUIT` is retrieved, `PeekMessage()` simply returns `TRUE` when *any* message is retrieved, and `FALSE` otherwise.  You have to check the `MSG` only when `PeekMessage()` returns `TRUE`.  There is no guarantee that the `MSG` is updated when `PeekMessage()` returns `FALSE`.  But you are checking the `MSG` only after `PeekMessage()` returns `FALSE`.

You need to check the `MSG` inside of your inner `while()` loop, as that is the only place that the `MSG` is guaranteed to contain valid data, eg:

```cpp
MSG msg;
while (true)
{
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
            return 0;
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    if (screen == TITLESCREEN) {
        drawTitleScreen();
    }

    if (screen == GAMESCREEN) {
        drawGameScreen();
    }
}
return 0;
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
MSG msg = { };
bool keepLooping = true;
do
{
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        {
            keepLooping = false;
            break;
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    if (!keepLooping) {
        break;
    }

    if (screen == TITLESCREEN) {
        drawTitleScreen();
    }

    if (screen == GAMESCREEN) {
        drawGameScreen();
    }
}
while (true);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not `msg.message` will ever be WM_QUIT where you test for it is not deterministic.

You are looping on the return value of PeekMessage. The return value of PeekMessage is true if a message was available. More than one message may be in the message queue and in such a case this loop will field all of the messages. Thus, for the WM_QUIT check to fire there would need to be a WM_QUIT message in the queue *and* it would need to be the last message in the queue before PeekMessage returns false. This may happen sometimes but you can't count on it happening all the time.